# Can every iterative function be converted into a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, iteration, language-agnostic

Nowadays some compilers can help us convert recursive functions into iterative, but my question is that can every iterative function has a recursive counterpart?

Answer (score 3):

Every iterative function can be converted to recursive, and vice versa. The Church-Turing hypothesis says that Turing Machines are a system of universal computation: that any computable function can be implemented as a Turing machine. If your language can implement Turing machines, it is Turing-equivalent, and therefore can compute any  computable function.

Can we implement a Turing machine using recursion with no iteration? Sure we can

```
TuringMachine(tape[1...n...], head, state)
    if state = halt_accept then return true
    if state = halt_reject then return false
    (t, h, s) = RunTransition(tape[head], state)
    tape[head] = t
    return TuringMachine(tape, h, s)
```

The function `RunTransition` just checks the transition table for a matching row for the current tape symbol and state, and returns the new tape symbol, tape head position and state. This should illustrate that, in principle, recursion is perfectly sufficient for implementing Turing machines, which means that any computable function can be solved by recursion (if you believe the Church-Turing hypothesis). Because iterative functions cannot do more than Turing Machines (again, if you accept the Church-Turing hypothesis) then any iterative procedure can be turned into a recursive one.

For loops are not hard to imagine:

```
function Foo()
    for i = 1 to n
        f(i)
Foo()

... becomes ...

function Foo(i)
    f(i)
    if i + 1 < n then foo(i + 1)

Foo(0)
```

While loops are similarly converted:

```
function Foo()
    condition = true
    while condition
        f()

Foo()

... becomes ...

Foo()
    if condition then
        f()
        Foo()

Foo()
```